# Distinct combinations of values based on a same column, while doing operations based on another

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, consider a table with columns like below, how can I get a distinct 2-tuple combination based on the values in `user`, while summing the `score` attribute of each pair?

```
user  | score
-------------
Tom   | 13
Sam   | 7
Larry | 66
Diana | 29
```

The expected output:

```
user1 | user2 | total_score
---------------------------
Tom   | Sam   | 20
Tom   | Larry | 79
Tom   | Diana | 42
Sam   | Larry | 73
Sam   | Diana | 36
Larry | Diana | 95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a sort-of `cross join`:

```
select t1.name, t2.name, (t1.score + t2.score) as total_score
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.name > t2.name;
```

Comment: Never thought about using things like `t1.name > t2.name`! Thanks for the idea, will try this out.

Comment: Not in the original question, but should I replace `join` with `cross join` and `on` with `where` if it's ANSI SQL? (I'm still learning SQL and use MySQL to test things out, but would like to know how things are different with other databases. Thanks!)

Comment: @jexplorer . . . They are equivalent. In this case, I would say the difference is a matter of preference.  Equality conditions should always use `join` with an `on` clause.